# Running distinct statement on Index - sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

```
sqlite> .schema movie
  CREATE TABLE movie (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, year INTEGER, nth TEXT, for_video BOOLEAN
    );
sqlite> select count(*) from movie;
  count(*)  
  ----------
  530256 
sqlite>
```

---

For query,  Which years in human history have seen at least one movie released?

```
$ sqlite movie.db
sqlite> select DISTINCT year from movie order by year asc;
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master where type='index';
  index|index1|movie|194061|CREATE INDEX index1 on movie (year)
sqlite> .quit
$
$ time printf "select DISTINCT year from movie order by year;" | sqlite3 movie.db > /dev/null 

real    0m0.086s
user    0m0.064s
sys     0m0.020s

$ time printf "select DISTINCT year from movie indexed by index1 order by year;" | sqlite3 movie.db > /dev/null 

real    0m0.092s
user    0m0.088s
sys     0m0.000s
```

---

My understanding is, to run select query on `movie`, without indexing, `530256` scans required, because table `movie` has `530256` records. To reduce these scans, `index1` is created on table `movie`using non-key field `year`.

On indexing, things are going worse.

---

Using indexing, Can select query with DISTINCT be optimised?

Does indexing enhance performance for sql query only **with** `WHERE` clause and **without** `GROUP BY`, that provides specific(single) group of results?

Comment: Does it **need** optimizing? Did you **try** adding an index?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen  yes, Because my query is going for 530256 scans. Can indexing reduce these scans?

Comment: It might. You will have to try it.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen After trying `time printf "select DISTINCT year from movie indexed by index1 order by year;" | sqlite3 movie.db > /dev/null`, I do not see much improvement in performance. How do I know/understand the number of scans taken on `index1`?

Comment: And you have that index present on the table?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, Query edited. Infact on indexing, things are  worse

Comment: When you said you had 530256 scans, was the index present then?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen 530256 scans without indexing, because you have 530256 records.

Comment: What do you get when you [`EXPLAIN` each query](https://sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) and compare the plans?

Comment: @BaconBits  Without out index, `SCAN table movie` & `USE TEMP B-TREE FOR DISTINCT `, two operations. With index `index1`, `SCAN TABLE movie USING COVERING INDEX index1`, single operation. Why `SCAN TABLE movie USING COVERING INDEX index1` is taking more time?

Comment: You have measured the time needed by the `printf` command. Use `.timer on` in the `sqlite3` shell instead.